# problema evento mousedown JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema, tengo un carrusel, un slider de 400% del ancho del viewport para 4 slides, cuando trato de obtener la coordenada del slider del eje "x" donde se hizo click del evento mousedown, me bota la coordenada del slider pero en base al tamaño del viewport (100% de ancho, como si fuera 1 solo slide) y no en base de todo el ancho del slider (400%)
Osea, si estoy en el slide 4, (en base a viewport de 1000px) me tendria que botar una coordenada de 3000px para arriba, no dentro de 1000px como si fuera de 1 slide.

```
<div class="slider">
        <ul class="slider__content">
            <li class="slider__item">
                <h2 class="slider__title" id="slider__titleOne">Dog 1</h2>
                <img src="dog1.jpg" draggable="false" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="slider__item">
                <h2 class="slider__title" id="slider__titleTwo">Dog 2</h2>
                <img src="dog2.jpg" draggable="false" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="slider__item">
                <h2 class="slider__title" id="slider__titleThree">Dog 3</h2>
                <img src="dog3.jpg" draggable="false" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="slider__item">
                <h2 class="slider__title" id="slider__titleFour">Dog  4</h2>
                <img src="dog4.jpg" draggable="false" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
<script>
        let slider = document.querySelector('.slider__content')
        let isDown = false
        let startPosition = 0
        slider.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
            isDown = true
            startPosition = e.offsetX
            console.log(startPosition)
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Prueba `clientX` en lugar de `offsetX`, aunque no creo que haya diferencia. En todo caso, consulta las propiedades disponibles en [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event)

Comment: Ya lo consulte, pero nada, es como si el e.target hiciera interferencia con el elemento que  tiene el mousedown

Comment: El evento es lanzado por el elemento donde se hizo clic, que, definitivamente, no es la lista, sino alguno de los hijos de cada `li`, ya sea el título o la imagen. Creo que lo importante es saber qué pretendes hacer con esas coordenadas, si realmente son necesarias, estás en un serio problema. Si solo las necesitas para saber hacia donde mover el elemento del slider, entonces no va a ser tan difícil.

Comment: Si, estaba haciendo clic en unos de sus hijos, `li, img, h3`, lo que hize fue darle a los  `li` un `z-index` negativo, para que el `ul` este delante y figure en el target, y me evitara problemas.